# it is possible to know the field value in .where() before .get()

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Simply I have the following query method:

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users')
            .where('count', isEqualTo: // here I need to use the current field value + 50 for example){...}
```

Is there a way to do that in the same query?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions). Transactions are helpful when you want to update the value of a field based on its current value. This means that when you perform a transaction, you can read the value in the field first, then you can perform some logic and in the end, you can finally commit the transaction.

Comment: thanks .. i know about transection but you are away from my question .. i only want to know the current field value while sorting . transection get the data then so ...

Comment: There is nothing in your question that refers to sorting. However, there is no way you can know the value of a specific field without reading it first. So in order to know the value of a specific field, you either have to perform a query and read the document or perform a transaction. That's it.

Comment: i know now that there is no way for doing it before .get() . imagine there is away for it then we could  get distance between two lang , lat and sort results according to it instead of geohash headache. i only wrote '+' in my question as example . but i have faith that there is away somehow. because if there is not so how firestore knows about field value and sort result according to it ?

Comment: It sounds like your question started off about knowing the value of a field before performing a Firestore query, but now you're talking about geo queries. At this point, you should think about asking a new question that illustrates what's the problem with geo queries.

Comment: I apologize if I wasn't very clear, but my foreword to geo queries was in order to clarify the purpose of my first question. and yes my question is about knowing the value of a field before performing a Firestore query,. so i want to know (WHILE) Firestore begins to handle with .where() before performing a Firestore query it seem that somehow it know what is the value is, Accordingly, it queries before the results being fetched . no ? so where is the value be saved at this time exactly?

Comment: Yes, your question is about knowing the value of a field before performing a Firestore query, and this question has already an answer. Regarding the second question, Firestore will use `.where()` while performing the query. Why? Because it needs to return the documents that satisfy that query. And no, the query starts only when you pass a concrete (known) value to the `.where()` function. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes Alex, so we couldn't know what is the value  before performing a Firestore query. that's also what @flutroid said in his answer , like direct answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that, You have to use `.get` or `.snapshots` to get documents first then get the field value.

Comment: thank you .. that's what i was expecting